# Removing fields in c++ vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iteration, erase-remove-idiom

I cannot grasp the idea and programm such a thing correctly (I'm a beginner):
I have a vector. Vector has lets say elements: fieldA, fieldB, fieldC. So having array of these vectors, I want to check, beginning with the last vector in the array, and going to the direction of the first one, if one of the elements has a specific value, lets say if (vect[i].fieldA == 0.0). In such a case, if (vect[i-1].fieldA == 0.0) so has the same value, I want to remove the whole vector from array. Can someone provide me with a part of code that will visualize, how to create the proper "back iteration" loop and use function to delete it? I was trying with erase(), remove(), deque() but I failed.

I don't want to mess here with my codes.

Thanks for help!

#### EDIT. So I first fed in a loop my array with vectors values, then I want to remove all vectors from the end, that contain element specific value, e.g. fieldA == 0.0

I want to cut the array, not only remove content of vectors!
There is proper inheritance between classB and classA so the feeding works well, I want only to solve this thing with deleting the vectors.
example: array of vectors of 2 elements. input: 0,1 0,3 3,3 2,3 0,6 5,6 0,8 0,7 0,6 output:0,1 0,3 3,3 2,3 0,6 5,6 0,8. conclusion: 0,7 and 0,6 vectors were removed.

```
    classA tmp;
    for (std::vector<std::classB>::iterator iter = newW.begin(); iter != newW.end(); iter++)
        {
        tmp.set_fieldA(iter->a);
        tmp.set_fieldB(iter->b);
        tmp.set_fieldC(iter->c);
        objA.push_back(tmp);
        }

    vector<std::classA> objA;
        for(int i = objA.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
        if (objA[i].fieldA == 0.0)
            if (objA[i-1].fieldA == 0.0)
                objA.erase(objA[i-1]); //remove last vector from array
        }
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand exactly what's going on from the question. If you show us your code so far someone might be able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Also if you remove a vector from an array, it means you're having a 2D array like vector of vectors?

Comment: @makciook I think the vector in this context is actually a `class` with members `fieldA`, etc, and these are being stored in an array (or possibly `std::vector`)? That's why I asked for the code; it's not exactly clear.

Comment: sorry guys, I now provided codes I wrote

Comment: At a first glance, one error I spot is that you declare your `std::vector<std::classA> objA` after the loop which is supposed to fill it. You should move the declaration above the first loop.

Comment: you can simply do `objA = newW;` to assign one `std::vector` to another..., no need to loop and use a temporary (much less than to copy field by field).

Answer (score 5):

I'm interpreting your code as follows. You have a **struct** named Vector with 3 members

```
struct Vector
{
    double fieldA;
    double fieldB;
    double fieldC;
}
```

The code below works as follows. It uses `std::find_if_not` with **reverse iterators**  (`rbegin()` and `rend()`) to find the first element from the back that has a `fieldA` different from `0`.  It then converts this to a regular iterator (using `base()`) and compares it to the end of the vector. Finally the call `v.erase` will actually erase them (the so-called **erase-remove idiom**)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{

   struct Vector { int fieldA; int fieldB; };
   std::vector<Vector> v = { 
      Vector{ 1, 0 }, Vector{ 2, 1 }, Vector{ 0, 2 }, Vector{ 1, 3 }, Vector{ 0, 4 }, 
      Vector{ 0, 5 }, Vector{ 5, 6 }, Vector{ 6, 7 }, Vector{ 0, 8 }, Vector{ 0, 9 }, Vector{ 0, 10} 
   };   

   for (auto& e: v) { std::cout << "{" << e.fieldA << "," << e.fieldB << "}, "; };
   std::cout << "\n";

   auto m = std::find_if_not(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), [&](Vector const& elem){
       return elem.fieldA == 0;
   }).base();

   if (m != v.end())
      // remove all but one matching element
      v.erase(m + 1, v.end());

   for (auto& e: v) { std::cout << "{" << e.fieldA << "," << e.fieldB << "}, "; };
   std::cout << "\n";   
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/M8iTg%2414)

Comment: it is not what I meant. I don't want to move any of elements in array if they contain 0. I want to remove them from the end of the array, so that at the end is a vector not containing 0 (because there might be no 0 at all), or only one vector containing 0, not more of them. example: 0,1 2,1 2,2 0,4 0,5 1,6 0,8 0,7 0,6 -> I want here to remove 0,7 and 0,6 and obtain **0,1 2,1 2,2 0,4 0,5 1,6 0,8**

Comment: @berndh Updated, with new code example. It leaves the 0,8 item at the back, but will remove any other trailing elements with a 0.

Comment: thanks, online I see it works, but when I try it in Visual I get error C2552: 'v' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list, v.push_back also doesn't work for me, as 'doesn't take multiple arguments'. do you have any suggestions here?

Comment: @berndh Visual C++ 2012 November CTP does have initializer lists, except for all library code (including `std::vector`). This will become available in the next release. In the mean time, just use a bunch of `push_back()` calls loading the items one by one, or create a `std::array` (where Visual C++ can use initializer lists) and make a loop that copies that array into the vector.

Comment: unfortunately this also does not work, find_if_not is not recognizable. is there any alternative approach ? (so that Visual would take)

Comment: @berndh replace `find_if_not` with `find_if` and the `fieldA==0` with `fieldA!=0`